# Asking JRE to run a jarfile on launching the java.exe

Tags: java, jar, discord, exe

I'm creating a game compatible with Discord's Rich Presence, and as Discord uses `exe` files to launch games, when I'm trying to launch my game from Discord, it starts the `java.exe` executable coming from the JRE instead of the jarfile of my game.

What I'm asking is, is there any way to copy jre (to bundle it with the game) and setup it to start automatically a specific jarfile ? If yes, how ?
If it's not possible, is there any way to launch a jar from an exe without launching java.exe separately ?
Thanks for your help.

- Sorry for bad English, I'm french

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 14 includes a [packaging tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/343) that allows exactly that. There are also tutorials available on how to do that, e.g. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java14-jpackage). In short, something like this should work:

```
jpackage --input target/ \
  --name MyApp \
  --main-jar myApp.jar \
  --main-class com.company.MyApp \
  --type exe \
  --java-options '--enable-preview'
```

If you are not yet using Java 14 but an older version, have a look at [WinRun4J](https://github.com/poidasmith/winrun4j) or [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net). Both allow creating exe-wrappers for Jar-Files, or creating an exe-file along with a JRE and a jar-File to run it independently. Those two only work for Windows, whereas the Java packaging tool will create executables for each platform (Windows, macOS, Linux) when run on the respective platform (it's not cross-platform capable, e.g. creating a macOS executable on Windows).

For macOS, there is [appbundler](https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler) which is able to create a .app with JRE and jar-File included, so users can just double click the application to start the java application.